# How to change color of an overlay image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to set the cactus image over the desert image. And have the green background of the cactus removed.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

image_desert = Image.open("desert.jpg")

image_cactus = Image.open("cactus.jpg")

image_cactus = image_desert.load()

for y in range (200, 300):
        for x in range (100, 200):
            (r, g, b) = image_cactus[x, y]

            newgreen = g + 30
            #choosing rgb colors
            image_cactus[x, y] = (r, newgreen, b)


image_desert.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated it.

Comment: Look at lines 3 and 4. What do you think is happening there?

Comment: image_cactus is displaying over image_desert? right?

Comment: How do you know what the background color of the cactus image is (i.e. the one you want changed)?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. I just know that the instruction was to remove the background of the cactus image. Like make the green background transparent or something

Comment: To do something like this you would need to know the key color (aka the [chroma key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key)).

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was interesting. I've never worked with picture manipulation before, so I wanted to give it a shot and see if I could figure it out. Let me know if this works for your purposes, or if it needs to be improved.

```
from PIL import Image

image_desert = Image.open("desert.jpg")

image_cactus = Image.open("cactus.jpg")

image_temp = image_desert.load()

image_cactus = image_cactus.load()

(rCactus, gCactus, bCactus) = image_cactus[0, 0]
#This gets the rgb value of the green background

for y in range (0, 600):
    for x in range (0, 600):
        (rResult, gResult, bResult) = image_cactus[x, y]

        if(gCactus <= gResult + 5 and gCactus >= gResult - 5):
            #this is a comparison of the cactus picture with the background pixel value.
            # There is a range of plus or minus 5 since the pixels change ever so slightly
            # near the edge of the cactus, so the range makes it look a little better.

            (rResult, gResult, bResult) = image_temp[x, y]
            #if the pixel in the cactus photo is within a range of 10 pixels of the 
            #known green background pixel value, it will be replaced with the pixel
            #from the desert photo.

        image_temp[x, y] = (rResult, gResult, bResult)

image_desert.show()
```

It's definitely not a perfect picture, photoshop would do a much better job. Getting rid of all of the green around the cactus is where I'm running into the biggest issue. The wider you make the range of pixels, the more your cactus may start disappearing and getting spotty.

Comment: wow that is perfect. I've spent like 2 days and couldn't figure it out. thanks so much